# Kotlin lambda function in RxJava subscription captures this reference even when not used

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, rx-java, rx-android

This is something I have unfortunately been stuck on for a while, and is an issue I did not see coming. But my understanding of both the LeakCanary report and the generated Kotlin Bytecode is that anonymous lambda functions passed to an Observable's subscribe function, always capture `this` as a variable, even when it is never referenced?

Or am I just completely wrong here, and is more going on that I am missing?

The specific code snippet in which I am trying to use a WeakReference to `this`.

```
class FiltersGroupView {
    private val instanceCompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun setup() {
        val weakSelf = WeakReference(this)
        ...
        setButton.clicks()
            .subscribe {
                weakSelf.get()?.setConsolidatedChanges()
            }
            .addTo(instanceCompositeDisposable)
    }
}
```

Generated Kotlin Bytecode for the subscribe's lambda function in the code snippet above.

[image]

Leak Canary:

```
├─ com.reelgoodapp.reelgood.ui.subclasses.RGButton$setOnClickListener$1 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 48 B in 3 objects
│    Anonymous class implementing android.view.View$OnClickListener
│    ↓ RGButton$setOnClickListener$1.$l
│                                    ~~
├─ com.jakewharton.rxbinding3.view.ViewClickObservable$Listener instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 32 B in 2 objects
│    ↓ ViewClickObservable$Listener.observer
│                                   ~~~~~~~~
├─ io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 48 B in 2 objects
│    ↓ LambdaObserver.onNext
│                     ~~~~~~
├─ com.reelgoodapp.reelgood.ui.recyclerview.holders.filters.entities.
│  FiltersGroupView$$special$$inlined$instance$lambda$5 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 20 B in 1 objects
│    Anonymous class implementing io.reactivex.functions.Consumer
│    $context$inlined instance of com.reelgoodapp.reelgood.ui.MainActivitySingleFragment with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ FiltersGroupView$$special$$inlined$instance$lambda$5.this$0
│                                                           ~~~~~~
```

I understand that disposing the CompsiteDisposable will clear this reference from memory, since it will dispose of the subscription and the associated lambda functions. But ideally I let the GC do that automatically by letting the class itself deinit, and with that the CompositeDisposable. But this obviously does not happen if the very same subscription creates a reference cycle.

What I am trying to accomplish, coming from iOS development, is something like Swift's

```
{ [weak self] in self?.setConsolidatedChanges() }
```

or Objective-C's

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    ...
});
```

Comment: You might wanna check [AutoDispose](https://uber.github.io/AutoDispose/)

Comment: As far as I understand (and I might be wrong), Kotlin generates SAM wrapper classes for lambdas and your `this` is a reference to that wrapper, not to enclosing class. Note the type of the local: `FiltersGroupView$$special$$inlined$instance$lambda$5`